# What is the rhetorical effect of this usage of Anastrophe in Shakespeare's Othello?

Tags: shakespeare, rhetorical-devices

When reading Othello, I found many expressions using anastrophe. Some of them are just for the metre, but some are truly fancinating and I am not able to analyse them quite well.

For example, in 2.3, when Iago had sent away Cassio and was all himself, he said

> And what’s he then that says I play the villain?
> When this advice is free **I give** and honest,

The normal phrase should be "When this advice I give is free and honest", which is also metrically correct—but Shakespeare still changed the order, why is that? Certainly now it reads more vivid, but how did Shakespeare think of it?

Comment: Perhaps the order asks us to question if Iago's advice, free, is also given with honesty.

Comment: Well, the word "free" is often glossed variously- mostly mentioned as just "bounteous, honourable" in Othello, and less "no payment".
For example, Iago just described that Desdemona "is of so free ... a disposition."

Comment: Might just be to match the structure of the previous sentence (with "I" in the same position). Questions about literary techniques and the effects they achieve belong on Literature SE though.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot ask the Bard. All of Shakespeare is full of these inversions. We use them in English for poetic emphasis. There are only reasons which people can surmise literarily and poetically.

Comment: This is probably literature criticism, not English language.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not strictly about language usage.  It is about the effect that metric rhythm has on what stands out in the line. It is well known that in iambic metre every second syllable is stressed.  In fact, in ancient Greek *lyric* poetry, the words were literally the words of songs written to be accompanied by the lyre.  The metre actually marked the lengths of notes, every second note of an iambic 'foot' twice as long as every first note.

There were at that time many far more complicated, syncopated metres.  With the arrival of spoken and acted as well as sung and danced (chorus) passages in staged tragedy and comedy, the metre of the spoken parts indicated stress more than length.

[I should add that, strictly speaking, the ancient Greek iambus  was actually of four syllables, and that variations between long and short were possible, so that, for example (especially in comedy) a some long syllables could be 'resolved' in two short syllables, and the first syllable could be long instead of short.]

If a writer for the Tudor stage places the words quoted here in the order of spoken standard English, the words "free and honest" flow together, so that "honest" gets the greater attention because it is at the end of the line and "free" is merged into it.  But if you move the phrase "is free back before "I give", the mind of listener is allowed to dwell on the fact that it is free advice, while the "I give" virtually goes without saying other than to complete the grammatically required sense.

You could achieve the same effect by saying

> "**My** advice is free <*pause pause>* and honest.

"I give" is a sort of pause that allows "is free" to carry its own independent weight rather than be merged into "and honest".

Comment: It's worth noting that some editions introduce a comma to the line to heighten the pause between free and honest. Here is the Riverside Shakespeare: "When this advice is free I give, and honest, / Probal to thinking, and indeed the course / To win the Moor again?" I think this editorial choice highlights the effect of the anaphora, offering meditation on *free* separate from *honest*.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin:- But do you think editions ought to do this?  A play script is like a musical score, where the composer has put in any pauses.  The displacement of the phrase does the job.

Comment: I don't see why not. Editing punctuation in early modern texts is a necessity because the conventions were different, and editors come to different conclusions about how to edit it.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin:  You can if you like, but to the extent that a published text of the play is concerned, there ought to be at least a footnote to make clear that the commas are an insert not in the original text, made for the sake of clarification.  Should we, for example, also edit the preceding line in some way, to conform with contemporary English usage?  There is nothing wrong with providing a modernised 'translation' of Shakespeare's lines, provided the publisher makes clear it is adapted. The same would apply to poems of Robbie Burns.  It is a translation, not a correction.

Comment: They already do. Editions of Shakespeare usually have an editor's note or the like noting their usual practices around sources, punctuation, and spelling. Also, there is no one original text for some of these plays, since the text may change between quarto and folio. What we think of as Shakespeare's original text is an invention by scholars. It's just how it's done. In *Riverside Shakespeare*, G. Blakemore Evans in "Shakespeare's Text" covers both textual history and (in "The Present Edition" subsection) the editorial practice, including for punctuation.